# Spring Boot Admin uses HTTP instead of HTTPS Actuator Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

After the registration at the Spring Boot Admin (SBA) Server, some actuators of the clients get adressed with `http://springapplication.com/actuator` instead of `https://springapplication.com/actuator`.
Why does it change the endpoints to HTTP and doesn´t stay at HTTPS? Is it customizable?

Here are some Logs and the Java/YML-Files.

Logs:

```
2018-07-02 06:13:27.683  INFO 3194 --- [-client-epoll-7] d.c.b.a.server.services.StatusUpdater    : Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(id=0d47f12b0a94, version=57, registration=Registration(name=springbootapplication-Name, managementUrl=https://springbootapplication.com/actuator, healthUrl=https://springbootapplication.com/actuator/health, serviceUrl=https://springbootapplication.com, source=http-api), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UP, details={}), statusTimestamp=2018-07-02T05:06:08.423Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={httptrace=Endpoint(id=httptrace, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/httptrace), flyway=Endpoint(id=flyway, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/flyway), loggers=Endpoint(id=loggers, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/loggers), health=Endpoint(id=health, url=https://springbootapplication.com/actuator/health), env=Endpoint(id=env, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/env), heapdump=Endpoint(id=heapdump, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/heapdump), scheduledtasks=Endpoint(id=scheduledtasks, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/scheduledtasks), mappings=Endpoint(id=mappings, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/mappings), beans=Endpoint(id=beans, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/beans), configprops=Endpoint(id=configprops, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/configprops), threaddump=Endpoint(id=threaddump, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/threaddump), metrics=Endpoint(id=metrics, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/metrics), conditions=Endpoint(id=conditions, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/conditions), auditevents=Endpoint(id=auditevents, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/auditevents), info=Endpoint(id=info, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/info), jolokia=Endpoint(id=jolokia, url=http://springbootapplication.com/actuator/jolokia)}), buildVersion=null)
```

Application.yml (Server):

```
server:
  port: 5100
spring: 
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: password
```

SecuritySecureConfig.java (Server):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.AdminServerProperties;

@Configuration
public class SecuritySecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final String adminContextPath;

    public SecuritySecureConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and().logout()
                .logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

SpringBootAdminApplication.java (Server):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "administration")
@PropertySource(value = "META-INF/build-info.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootAdminApplication.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application.yml (Client):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: springapplication
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        username: ${application.security.usernameAdmin}
        password: ${application.security.passwordAdmin}
        url: "https://springBootAdminServerURL.com"
        instance:
          service-base-url: https://http://springapplication.com/
          metadata:
            user.name: ${application.security.usernameAdmin}
            user.password: ${application.security.passwordAdmin}                 
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
application:
  security:
    usernameAdmin: admin
    passwordAdmin: password
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Look at your applications `/actuator` endpoint. Is it reporting urls as http? It did for me, even if health used https. What solved it for me was adding `server.use-forward-headers=true` which adds all `X-Forwarded-*`, including the `X-Forwared-Proto` that identifies scheme (http/https).

Remember if your app is behind a reverse proxy like NGINX, you'd also need to configure this. Example for NGINX

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Need correction in the config file for below property which signifies as

> Base url for computing the service-url to register with. The path is
>   inferred at runtime, and appended to the base url.

```
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url


instance:
          service-base-url: https://springapplication.com/
```

Comment: Hey Rizwan, thank you for your reply. After changing the `service-base-url` to `service-url` the Client registered itself on the Server, but stays inactive. The URL's for the actuators also stay http.

Comment: Service url is same for all instances of the same application. So, how to capture each instance metrics instead of service url when SSL enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is usually due to two issues.

1. Incorrect port configs
2. Untrusted SSL certs

To fix the first issue, you need to make sure your client application correctly informs Eureka to use the secure port:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnable: false
    securePortEnabled: true
```

To fix the second, you need to ensure the SSL cert is trusted by the JVM that is running Spring Boot Admin. Just install your cert into the JRE's cacert file using keytool. I would recommend enabling SSL debug logging while trying to get this to work.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=SSL
```

These two steps solved this issue for me.